# Flutter - how to disable navigation animation in auto_route

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, navigation

I want to disable the page transition animation when navigating to new pages and I am using the auto_route package.

```
          ///
      @AutoRouterConfig(replaceInRouteName: 'Page,Route')
      class AppRouter extends $AppRouter {
        @override
        List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
              AutoRoute(
                path: '/',
                page: Dashboard.page,
                children: [
                  AutoRoute(
                    path: 'posts',
                    page: Posts.page,
                    children: [
                      AutoRoute(path: 'nestedposts', page: NestedPosts.page),
                    ],
                  ),
                  AutoRoute(path: 'users', page: Users.page),
                ],
              )
            ];
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

In AppRouter
Override defaultRouteType => RouteType.custom()

Comment: Where does this go?

Comment: You can override it in AppRouter

Comment: Example app_router.dart:

'''
@AutoRouterConfig()
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {
  @override
  RouteType get defaultRouteType => const RouteType.custom();
...
'''

Answer (score 0):

To disable animation in `AutoTabsRouter` you need to add simple bellow code

```dart
transitionBuilder: (_, child, __) => child
```